# Keras Custom Binary Cross Entropy Loss Function. Get NaN as output for loss

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I try writing a custom binary cross-entropy loss function. 
This is my script:

```
def my_custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    t_loss = (-1)*(y_true * K.log(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred))
    return K.mean(t_loss)
```

When I run my script using this loss function, after few iterations, I get NaN as output for loss function.

Then I looked at TensorFlow documentation, I modified the loss function into the following:

```
 t_loss = K.max(y_pred,0)-y_pred * y_true + K.log(1+K.exp((-1)*K.abs(y_pred)))
```

The code runs without any issue. 
I would like to know if someone could provide some explanation why my first loss function gives a NaN output.

Binary Cross-Entropy: y * log(p) + (1-y) * log(1-p)

I have sigmoid function as activation for my last layer.
So the value of 'p' should be between 0 and 1. Log should exist for this range.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

A naive implementation of Binary Cross Entropy will suffer numerical problem on 0 output or larger than one output, eg `log(0) -> NaN`. The formula you posted is reformulated to `ensure stability and avoid underflow`. The following deduction is from [tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits).

```
z * -log(sigmoid(x)) + (1 - z) * -log(1 - sigmoid(x))
= z * -log(1 / (1 + exp(-x))) + (1 - z) * -log(exp(-x) / (1 + exp(-x)))
= z * log(1 + exp(-x)) + (1 - z) * (-log(exp(-x)) + log(1 + exp(-x)))
= z * log(1 + exp(-x)) + (1 - z) * (x + log(1 + exp(-x))
= (1 - z) * x + log(1 + exp(-x))
= x - x * z + log(1 + exp(-x))
```

For x < 0, to avoid overflow in exp(-x), we reformulate the above

```
x - x * z + log(1 + exp(-x))
= log(exp(x)) - x * z + log(1 + exp(-x))
= - x * z + log(1 + exp(x))
```

And the implementation use the equivalient form:

```
max(x, 0) - x * z + log(1 + exp(-abs(x)))
```