# What is wrong with my custom cross entropy loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, math

I am training a U-Net model for binary segmentation of objects and foreground. Currently I am trying to recreate cross entropy function, to allow myself to ad a hyperparameter to it. This hyperparameter would enable higher penalization of incorrect object pixel marking compared to background pixel. This is necessary because the pixels of the objects in training set tend to take up the lesser fraction of overall pixels. Idea for this comes from: Aerial LaneNet: Lane Marking Semantic
Segmentation in Aerial Imagery using
Wavelet-Enhanced Cost-sensitive Symmetric Fully
Convolutional Neural Networks (equation 11)

@https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06904

I have tried various values for 
`lambda_lane`
including 1, which should yield the same results as tensorflow.keras.losses.binarty_cross_entropy(), yet it does not.

This is my attempt at recreating the function.

```
def binary_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
  N = 512. ** 2
  lambda_lane = 1e0
  y_true_f = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])
  y_pred_f = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1]) 
  loss =  tf.reduce_sum(lambda_lane * y_true_f * tf.math.log(y_pred_f) + (1. - y_true_f) * tf.math.log(1. - y_pred_f)) 
  return  -loss/N
```

During training my loss value exists for dozen or so steps (depending on the learning rate), then it goes to inf for a couple steps and after that it`s value is nan (going forward the accuracy approaches 0).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951109/keras-custom-binary-cross-entropy-loss-function-get-nan-as-output-for-loss

Comment: @akhetos Indeed this does solve my problem, thank you. But still, why does my original solution not work?

Comment: I don't know but I also would like to know the answer ^^. It's a bit strange if you'r loss work at the begining because you shouldnt be able to compute `y_true_f * tf.math.log(y_pred_f)` if `y_pred_h=0`...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with this function. The only possible source of the problem I can find is the fact that you are using a constant `N` which can be incorrect. You should use `N = tf.size(y_true_f)`.

Comment: N is a constant specific to my problem, it represents image size, which is (512 x 512 x 1), i just did`t bother to make that applicable to other problems, as I was battling the nan.